# Getting Google's Toolbar PageRank programmatically with Ruby

Tags: ruby, pagerank

This [well documented answer](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3284) no longer appears to work. The response doesn't contain the `/Rank_1:\d:(\d+)/` pattern.

I'm trying this with ruby-1.8.7. Interestingly, if I do it with ruby-1.9.2 I get a 403 Forbidden error using the same code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PageRankr](https://github.com/blatyo/page_rankr) gem.

Usage example:

```
require 'page_rankr'
PageRankr.ranks('http://google.com', :google)
```

Which returns hash

```
{:google=>9}
```

Comment: I tried this with 1.7.1 of that gem and kept getting -1:

    irb(main):011:0> PageRankr.rank('www.google.com', :google)
    => {:google=>-1}
    irb(main):012:0> PageRankr.rank('http://www.google.com', :google)
    => {:google=>-1}
    irb(main):013:0> PageRankr.rank("http://www.google.com", :google)
    => {:google=>-1}
    irb(main):014:0> PageRankr.rank("http://google.com", :google)
    => {:google=>-1}
    irb(main):015:0> PageRankr.ranks("http://google.com", :google)
    => {:google=>-1}

Comment: @Bradley 1.9.3p125 :009 > require 'page_rankr'
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :010 > PageRankr.ranks('http://google.com', :google)
 => {:google=>9} 
1.9.3p125 :012 > PageRankr.ranks('google.com', :google)
PageRankr::DomainInvalid: The domain provided is invalid.

Comment: I used PageRankr-3.1.2 on ruby 1.9.3. https://rubygems.org/gems/PageRankr this is current version.

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work by using the following in my Gemfile: `gem 'PageRankr', '~> 3.1.2'